# Virtual socket vs core per socket Best practise

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

Is this right way of assigning 8 Cpu's on Vmware?

I have research but couldn't find a right answer. What is the difference between virtual socket and core per socket.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference at all. By VMWare's own admission (I tried googling for it but couldn't find it, although I know I've given this answer on this site before), that option exists so that you can stay within the licensing restrictions for non-VM-aware applications that might be licensed per socket.

For eight CPUs you can assign 1 socket, 8 cores, or 2 sockets 4 cores, or 4 sockets, 2 cores.

Makes no difference.

Comment: Correct:

"Some operating system SKUs are hard-limited to run on a fixed number of CPUs. For example, Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition is limited to run on up to 4 CPUs. If you install this operating system on an 8-socket physical box, it runs on only 4 of the CPUs"

Check also KB 1010184 on VMware site https://kb.vmware.com/kb/1010184

Comment: This is only half of the story. While this feature was implemented for licensing reasons back then (thus: the KB is still valid) today much changed. We now have vNUMA and NUMA aware applications and depending on your hardware architecture and your application this settings WILL impact performance. Read https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2013/10/does-corespersocket-affect-performance.html and the vSphere Performance best practices about NUMA and vNUMA for more information.